# mapDispatchToProps: Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Below is the CreateCoursePage component where I use react-redux to manage the state after some database operations. However  `dispatch(CreateCourse(course)` statement inside `mapDispatchToProps` throws this exception:  `TS2345  (TS) Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.`

```
interface CreateCourseProps {
    error: string;
    createCourse: (course: Course) => ReturnType<typeof CreateCourse>;
}

const CreateCoursePage: React.FC<CreateCourseProps> = ({ createCourse }) => {
    
    const onSubmit = (course: Course) => {
        createCourse(course);
    };

    return (
        //other code
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
    error: state.courseReducer.error
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
    createCourse: (course: Course) => dispatch(CreateCourse(course)), 
});

const ConnectedCreateCourse = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateCoursePage);
export default ConnectedCreateCourse;
```

Below is the CreateCourse function defined in DataOperations.tsx:

```
export function CreateCourse(course: CourseData) {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {

        dispatch(CourseDopStarted());

        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'api/Course/CreateCourse',
            data: course
        }).then(response => {
            console.log('Course is created.');

            dispatch(CreateCourseSuccess(response.data as CourseData));

            toast.success("Course is created successfully!", {
                position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER
            });
        })
            .catch(error => {
                dispatch(CourseDopFailed(error))
            });
    }
}
```

Adding `as any` (`dispatch(CreateCourse(course) as any`) solves this issue but this is not a good practice in TS. I found some solutions but could not relate them with my own case. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the core `Dispatch` type doesn't know anything about thunks, just plain action objects.

The *best* answer here is:

- Stop using `connect`
- Switch to using the modern React-Redux hooks API
- Follow our guidelines for setting up a Redux store and inferring the correct type for `dispatch` from the store, and use a pre-typed version of the `useSelector` hook:

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start